# testng - passing parameters from a separate XML file

Tags: java, xml, testng

Im using testng.

using @Parameters im passing parameters:

@Parameters({"LoginCredentials"})

and in testng.xml , im doing the following:

`<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">`

`<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >`

`<test name="Regression Test Suite ">`

```
<parameter name="LoginCredentials" value="src\test\resources\Login.xml"/>
```

`<classes>`
        `<class name="com.sample.testcases.LoginTest" />`
        `<class name="com.sample.testcases.PollTest"/>`
        `</classes>`

`</test>`

`</suite>`

But when I run it , its not reading from the Login.xml file.

This is Login.xml contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

`<parameter name="strUserName" value="MVC"/>`

`<parameter name="strPasword" value="mypassword"/>`

Please tell me , how should I read parameters from a separate XML file and call it from testng.xml file.

Comment: show us your class com.sample.testcases.LoginTest, this class will get the file path ""src\test\resources\Login.xml". Inside that you have to use a method to extract the tags from login.xml and use the values. I dont think testng has any such ability to read the values from an xml all by itself. Show us your class implementation

Answer (score 0):

From what you have done. Inside the class logintest you will get the filepath which you will have to use to get the tag values. look at [this](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-testng-xml)